# Why set factory in DefinitionDecorator instead of set new class with calls directive?

Tags: symfony, foselasticabundle

There is part of code in FOSElasticaExtension [Extension class](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/FOSElasticaExtension.php#L149)

```
$Def = new DefinitionDecorator('foo');
$Def->replaceArgument(0, $bar);
$Def->addTag('baz', array( 'name' => $qux, ));
$Def->setFactory(array(new Reference('quux'), 'corge'));
```

so in yaml it might look like this:

```
services:
   foo:
       arguments:
           - '$bar'
       tags:
           -  { name: baz } 
       factory: ["@quux", corge]
```

Why set factory in DefinitionDecorator instead of set new class with `calls:` directive?

```
services:
   foo:
       arguments:
           - '$bar'
       tags:
           -  { name: baz } 
       class: @quux
       calls: corge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please write a code example how you would expect it to look like? I don't really get the point of your question.

To generically answer why it's done like this you have to understand how Symfony compiles the service container. The service container has a huge impact on performance that's why it's compiled after the tree is completely built, which is after instantiating all the extensions. That also means that your extension doesn't really have the classes, but only references to classes. I assume the index class is not registered as a service and that's why it must be retrieved via the registered client service which is used as a factory. I hope this answers your question, if not feel free to expand your question or add a comment.

edit: That is an interesting question. I checked Symfony's DependencyInjection, but from a cursory glance I can't find how exactly both approaches are different. From checking [DefinitionTest](https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection/blob/dd6d8f0b4540b4ecc8278f32b4b2046146d687ad/Tests/DefinitionTest.php) I assume it's possible to do something like:

```
$def->setMethodCalls(array(array($factoryReference,'getIndex')));
```

which looks a bit more complicated. This might be why setFactory was preferred.

Comment: i edited main post. My main concern is about the point of using factory inside decorator instead of simple method calls

Comment: see my edit. I don't think there is a major difference so it comes down to which you think looks nicer and foselasticabundle seems to have gone with the factory.